# How to describe fat curve (curved line of variable thickness)?

Tags: graphics, curve, bezier

I know how to describe curved line of constant thickness (with Bezier or similar models).

Are there any common models of curved line with variable thickness?

I am imagining some similar things like in Bezier. For example, each node can contain thickness value and it's weight, so renderer would interpolate thickness along curve.

Is there some implementations and/or descriptions?

**UPDATE**

More precisely the question is follows.

Suppose we have cubic Bezier segment, controlled by 4 points ABCD

[image]

In Bezier, the longer we have vector, say AB, then the longer curve follows AB direction. On the picture above, we have raltively long following.

So, I want thikness behave synchronously with control nodes B and C. If AB and CD is long, then thinkness should follow end nodes thinkness long and change to another thickness fast, like below

[image]

and if control vectors are short, then thinkness should smoothly change from one to another, like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Metafont](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafont) and its successor [MetaPost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaPost)
support variable thickness in the form of shaped pens.

See also

> L.M. Mestetskii, Fat curves and representation of planar figures, *Computers & Graphics*, 24:1 (2000) 9-21 doi: [10.1016/S0097-8493(99)00133-8](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097849399001338)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a "disc based" approach, you need to draw circles around every control point, then find the points on those circles that represent the "offset" (normal to the tangent, for on-curve points, normal to the tangent of the projection for off-curve points). You then plug those new points into the Bezier functions to get your "offset curve".

Curve offsetting, in your case with variable width, is essentially the trick of finding an outline rather than a single curve. For Bezier curves you can find a full explanation over at http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#offsetting, with the variable width explanation over at http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#offsetting  (you're interested in the latter, but you need to understand the basics before you look at the special case =)

Comment: Finding outline is second step. Currently I can't figure out how to represent curve itself. Assigning radius to each Bezier control point looks giving too smoothed thickness...

Comment: you can split up your curve into a polybezier at each point where you want to vary the width differently, then offset each segment separate and interpolate the joins

Comment: I want most simple description of one Bezier segment, like quadratic or cubic segments.

Comment: your new edit is kind of a completely different description of what you want, and is covered by the article links I gave.

Comment: can you give more precise answer? What data to store in the structure to describe fat segment? Your first paragraph says to assign radius to each control point, which gives 4 radii per one cubic segment, while I expect only 2 radii per cubic segment.

Comment: did you read the sections? If not, first off: you cannot generically create an offset curve for a Bezier curve using only one other Bezier curve. So there's the first problem - whether you have two or a thousand circles, unless you first chop up your curve into a poly-Bezier, you're not going to be able to perform any kind of sensible offsetting. I strongly recommend reading the article sections I linked to first.